# Can I loop through documents within a Firestore Transaction?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to run multiple document updates within one firestore transaction and I am wondering whether or not this is an anti pattern.

I have a document named "Group" containing an array named "members" which contains different IDs from a users collection. Now I want to loop through all members and update the according user documents within one transaction. Is this possible?

I have tried to loop through all members with .forEach() but the problem is that .forEach() does not support async/await or the use of promises as far as I know.

Comment: What you have tried....!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```js
    var firestore = firebase.firestore();

    //.....

    var groupDocRef = firestore.doc('collectionRef/docRef');

    return firestore
              .runTransaction(function(transaction) {
                var arrayOfMemberIds;
                return transaction
                  .get(groupDocRef)
                  .then(function(groupDoc) {
                    if (!groupDoc.exists) {
                      throw 'Group document does not exist!';
                    }
    
                    arrayOfMemberIds = groupDoc.data().members;
    
                    return transaction.update(groupDocRef, {
                      lastUpdate: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
                    });

                  })
                  .then(function() {

                    arrayOfMemberIds.forEach(function(memberId) {
                      transaction = transaction.update(
                        firestore.collection('users').doc(memberId),
                        { foo: 'bar' }
                      );

                    });
    
                    return transaction;
                  });
              });
```

This will work because the [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Transaction.html#update) method returns the Transaction instance which can be used for chaining method calls.

Note also that we must update the initial `groupDoc`. If not, the following error will be thrown: `FirebaseError: "Every document read in a transaction must also be written."`. In the example above we just update a `lastUpdate` field with a Timestamp. It's up to you to choose the update you want to do!

---

You can easily test the transactional aspect of this code by setting some security rules as follows:

```js
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
        match /collectionRef/{doc} {
          allow read: if true;
        }
    
        match /users/{user} {
          allow read: if false;
        }
    
      }
    }
```

Since it is not possible to write to the `users` collection, the `Transaction` will fail and the `collectionRef/docRef` document will **NOT** be updated.

---

Another (even better) way to test the transactional aspect is to delete one of the `users` document. Since the `update()` method fails if applied to a document that does not exist, the entire `Transaction` will fail.